# I am not able to understand the difference between c style casting(for ex:- A a;B *b;b = (*B) (&a);) and dynamic_cast<B*>(&a);

Tags: c++

I searched on google about dynamic_cast and I found that explicitly casting base class object to derive class pointer can be unsafe.
But when I ran some sample code to check this I am not getting any errors. 
Please find my code below:

```
class A
{
    virtual void get(){}
};

class B : public A
{
    public: void print(void)
    {
        cout << "In B's print" << endl;
    }
    void get()
    {
        cout <<" In B's get" << endl;
    } 
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    //A *a1 = &a;
    B* b;
    b = (B*)(&a);//c-style casting base class object to derive class pointer
    b->print();
    /*b = dynamic_cast<B*>(&a); // dynamic casting base class object to derive class pointer
    if(b)
            b->print();
    else
    cout << "failed" << endl;*/
}

Run: c++ cast.cpp
Run: ./a.out
o/p:- In B's print
```

As far as I know ,b->print() should fail as base class does not have all information about derive class.

If I run the same code with dynamic_cast it will return null after casting and the output will be failed.

Can somebody clear my doubt? Also please correct me if anything is wrong or inappropriate.

Comment: Whenever you see `dynamic_cast` or `reinterpret_cast` in combination with classes, chances are someone somewhere does not do a particularly good job. Even worse are the C style casts. Avoid casting and rethink the design. The only cast you should be using is the `static_cast` if that.

Comment: How your `virtual`s are supposed to work if `A` and `B` are unrelated? Casting between unrelated classes is UB.

Comment: Add members to both `A` and `B` and display them in your (virtual or not) function. You should have your expected error.

Comment: sorry I forgot to add class B: public A line.

Comment: "As far as I know, b->print() should fail" is incorrect.  It is not "should fail", rather it is "undefined behavior".  Undefined behavior may appear to do something sensible, or may crash.  I recommend never using a cast.  If you find you think you need a cast, instead try to fix the problem without using any cast.

Answer (score 6):

With [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) you get a runtime check that what you cast indeed *can* be casted to what you want.

With a C-style cast you basically tell the compiler "I know what I'm doing, don't get in my way". Which is a great way to shoot yourself in the foot if you make a mistake. A C-style cast is similar to [`reinterpret_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) but less safe.

In this case, because `&a` is *not* a pointer to `B`, you do indeed shoot yourself in the foot, since the pointer `b` will be pointing to something that's not a `B`. That leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) if you attempt to dereference `b` in any way.

Comment: Also, C style casts are very difficult to search for, whereas static_cast and the like are much more unique strings.